# Why is "do" allowed inside a function?

Tags: f#, language-specifications

I noticed that the following code compiles and works in VS 2013:

```
let f() =
    do Console.WriteLine(41)
    42
```

But when looking at the F# 3.0 specification I can't find any mention of `do` being used this way. As far as I can tell, `do` can have the following uses:

- As a part of loop (e.g. `while expr do expr done`), that's not the case here.
- Inside computation expressions, e.g.:

  ```
  seq {
      for i in 1..2 do
      do Console.WriteLine(i)
      yield i * 2
  }
  ```

  That's not the case here either, `f` doesn't contain any computation expressions.

  Though what confuses me here is that according to the specification, `do` should be followed by `in`. That `in` should be optional due to lightweight syntax, but adding it here causes a compile error (“Unexpected token 'in' or incomplete expression”).
- Statement inside a module or class. This is also not the case here, the `do` is inside a function, not inside a module or a class.

I also noticed that with `#light "off"`, the code doesn't compile (“Unexpected keyword 'do' in binding”), but I didn't find anything that would explain this in the section on lightweight syntax either.

Based on all this, I would assume that using `do` inside a function this way should not compile, but it does. Did I miss something in the specification? Or is this actually a bug in the compiler or in the specification?

Comment: It's called a `do` binding. I couldn't find it in the spec, but it's [documented on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd393786.aspx).

Comment: @Daniel That's the third case I mentioned, `do` inside a module. “Use a do binding when you want to execute code *independently of a function*”

Comment: To finish the quote: _independently of a function *or value definition*._ The second case could be applicable within a function.

Comment: The definition of _module-function-or-value-defn_ is possibly relevant here: `module Foo = do ()` doesn't compile either with `#light "off"`.

Comment: _Independently of a function_ would describe top-level `do` bindings (in a module or class constructor). Other `do` bindings could appear anywhere a `unit` expression is allowed.

Comment: @Daniel In the spec, it's in §10.2.5 for modules and §8.6.1.3 for classes. In either cases, I didn't find anything about `do` bindings in functions.

Comment: @kaefer That's because you're using light syntax, `module Foo = begin do () end` does compile with `#light "off"`.

Comment: Apparently it's missing from the spec.

Comment: The spec isn't 100% comprehensive.

Answer (score 7):

From the [documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd393786.aspx):

> A `do` binding is used to execute code without defining a function or value.

Even though the spec doesn't contain a comprehensive list of the places it is allowed, it is merely an expression asserted to be of type `unit`. Some examples:

```
if ((do ()); true) then ()
let x: unit = do ()
```

It is generally omitted. Each of the preceding examples are valid without `do`. Therefore, `do` serves only to *assert* that an expression is of type `unit`.

Comment: I think the spec disallows it, since it isn't listed as one of the choices for `expr` (§6 and §A.2.3).

Comment: Over the past few years I've seen many examples of `do` used in a function or method. If this behavior isn't intentional, it is de facto valid at this point. However, I think that isn't the case and the spec is incomplete on this point.

Answer (score 0):

Going through the [F# 3.0 specification](http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/3.0/FSharpSpec-3.0-final.pdf) expression syntax has `do expr` as a choice of `class-function-or-value-defn` (types) [Ch 8, A.2.5] and `module-function-or-value-defn` (modules) [Ch 10, A.2.1.1].

I don't actually see in the spec where `function-defn` can have more than one expression, as long all but the last one evaluate to `unit` -- or that all but the last expression is ignored in determining the functions return value.

So, it seems this is an oversight in the documentation.

Comment: “I don't actually see in the spec where `function-defn` can have more than one expression” That's thanks to the `expr = expr; expr` rule and the fact that lightweight syntax makes the semicolon optional.